# Only for simply connected Lie group, every representation of its Lie algebra can be integrated to a group representation (Hall Theorem 5.6)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

On Wikipedia:

> [Since the group SU(2) is simply connected, every representation of its Lie algebra can be integrated to a group representation (Hall 2015 Theorem 5.6).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)#Lie_algebra_representations)

From Hall's book, we see his Theorems ---

Theorem 5.6. Let G and H be matrix Lie groups with Lie algebras $g$ and $h$; respectively, and let $\phi: g \to h$ be a Lie algebra homomorphism. If G is simply connected, there exists a unique Lie group homomorphism $\Phi: G \to H$ such that $\Phi(e^x) = e^{\phi(x)}$ for all $X \in g$. This result has the following corollary.

Corollary 5.7. Suppose G and H are simplyconnected matrix Lie groups with Lie algebras $g$ and $h$, respectively. If $g$ is isomorphic to $h$; then G is isomorphic to H .

**Question: Would this fact fail when the group is not simply connected? Like SO(3)? or others PU(n) =PSU(n)? Why? Or is there a modified theorem?**

Answer (score 4):

> Would this fact fail when the group is not simply connected? Like SO(3)? or others PU(n) =PSU(n)?

Yes, it fails (miserably) : just take a non simply connected group $H$ and its universal cover $G$. Then $\mathfrak{g} =\mathfrak{h}$ but obviously $H$ and $G$ are not isomorphic.

> Why?

Morally, this is because, Lie algebras are infinitesimal in nature, they depend only on how the group looks like around the identity element. Therefore, they can't "see" the $\pi_1$.

> Or is there a modified theorem?

A modified theorem, could be : a representation of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of a group $G$ can be integrated in a group representation of its universal cover $\tilde{G}$.

Comment: That is a simple answer - but it seems true... +1

Comment: But my question was:  representation of its Lie algebra can be integrated to a group representation (Hall Theorem 5.6) of not simply connected Lie group?

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS In general, the answer is no : if $G$ is the universal cover of $H$ (non simply connected), then $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g}$. Yet, clearly, the identity $id : \mathfrak{h} \to\mathfrak{g}$ doesn't integrate to a group representation $H\to G$.

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS:  I think you may be missing this fact:  an $n$-dimensional (complex, quaternionic, real) representation of a group $H$ can be thought of as a homomorphism $H\rightarrow G$ where $G = U(n), Sp(n), SO(n)$, respectively.   So, if in Ayoub's last comment, if you take $G = SU(2)$ and $H = SO(3)$, then you find examples of representations of $\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathfrak{h}$ which don't integrate to representations of $H$.

Comment: Dear Jason, yes, =(2)  and =(3) are examples in my mind.

Comment: @Jason, so the representation of =(2) contains also the representation of =(3). how can the specific representation of =(2) that is also the representation of =(3), say the 3-dimensional vector representation of =(3), be integrated to the Lie group SU(2)? That is my puzzle, too.

Comment: Can the 3-dimensional vector representation of =(3) (which is also an adjoint representation of SU(2)), be integrated to the Lie group SU(2)? That is my puzzle,

Comment: Yes, because $SU(2)$ is simply connected.  This turns out to be precisely the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$.